# Advantages of static_cast over explicit instantiation/construction?

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

Considering the following function template `func` declared within `MyClass` class template:

```
template < T >
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() = default;

    // ...

    template < typename oT >
    oT func() {
        return static_cast< oT >(_m);  // alternative, return oT(_m);
    }

    // ...

 protected:
    T _m;
};
```

Is there any advantage in calling `static_cast< oT >(_m)` over explicit instantiation i.e. `oT(_m)`?

Comment: It's easier to find/edit/diagnose usage of the `static_cast` than it is for function-style casts.

Comment: [Different error messages](https://godbolt.org/z/3fEj61e1x). Opinion which is easier to read.

Comment: What you are calling is "_explicit instantiation_" is not explicit instantiation (that is a technical term with a specific meaning in C++). What you mean is _functional-style explicit cast_.

Answer (score 5):

`oT(_m)` will allow many more conversions than is probably intended. If `static_cast<oT>(_m)` wouldn't be possible, then `oT(_m)` will also try a `const_cast`, `static_cast` followed by `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.

For example if `T` is `const int*` and `oT` is `double*`, then `oT(_m)` will succeed, while `static_cast<oT>(_m)` will fail. But using the result from `oT(_m)` as if it was a pointer to a `double` will result in undefined behavior.

If `T` and `oT` are pointers to classes that is maybe even more dangerous, since `oT(_m)` will always compile, whether or not there is an inheritance relation between the two classes.

Even `static_cast` allows for some conversions that may not be intended. For example it can downcast pointers to classes.

Another alternative is simply `return _m;`. This is weaker than both variants above. It will only allow for copy-initialization. However that might be *too* weak depending on your use case. For example it will not use explicit constructors and conversion functions. On the other hand before C++17 it doesn't require `oT` to be move-constructible, which the first two variants do require before C++17.

So you will need to decide what casts are supposed to be allowed and which ones are supposed to fail.

However, nothing prevents a user from calling `func<T>()` to obtain the original type anyway and the user can then simply cast it however they like, so I am not sure what is gained here over a simple getter.

Even more so, the user can in either case call `func<T&>()` and will get a reference to the member, thereby making the `protected` somewhat pointless. Maybe the allowed types `T` need to be constrained via SFINAE/requires-clause.

Comment: The example in the question is just a simplified snippet, the actual implementation does in fact implement a SFINAE check w/ `is_constructible< oT, T >`. Also, the main point of `func` is just to provide a different (e.g. derived) interface "inline" without requiring instantiation & conversion externally e.g. `foo.func<SomeType>.someOtherFunction()` (though I've just now realized the return type should be perharps `oT&`)

Comment: @joaocandre `is_constructible` basically tests for direct-initialization, so the set of possible casts is going to roughly lie between those allowed by copy-initialization (`return _m`) and `static_cast`. In that case using `static_cast<oT>(_m)` or `oT(_m)` never makes a difference I think (could be that there are some unusual edge cases I am not thinking of). Before C++17 both variants also require the type to be move-constructible, which `return _m;` doesn't and `is_constructible<oT,T>` doesn't check for.

Comment: @joaocandre Returning `oT&` will not compile in most cases and cause undefined behavior in others, since `static_cast<oT>(_m)` results in a `oT` temporary to which you would return a dangling reference.

Comment: It was actually a typo - I meant `is_convertible< oT, T >`, though I am not sure if it makes a difference regarding your point. As for the return type, wouldn't the appropriate call be `static_cast<oT&>(_m)`?

Comment: @joaocandre `is_convertible` checks basically that `return _m;` is well-formed. So it will also not allow explicit constructors and conversion functions. With `static_cast<oT&>(_m)` you should however also test `is_convertible< oT&, T>`. In the end it will allow only implicit conversions, so basically it can only cast to base classes. But if `oT` is a `const` type there can still be trouble, since it may cause construction of a temporary as well, e.g. `T=int` and `oT=const long`.